# AWS Nodejs official SDK support for getSignedUrl with CloudFront & RTMP

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have searched here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/frames.html under CloudFront and I don't see a method to generate a signed url for my RTMP endpoint using NodeJs SDK. I realize S3 has the method:

```
(String?) getSignedUrl(operation, params, callback)
Get a pre-signed URL for a given operation name.
```

Does this method exist for CloudFront? I know the procedure exists according to this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-canned-policy.html

If not, are there any alternate method to generating a signed url? I want the link to stop working after a minute or so because I don't want someone to steal my links and download content. Am I approaching this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now AWS Nodejs SDK does not support getSignedUrl with CloudFront.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/frames.html

It is possible with .net & co, but not yet with Nodejs. Some developers prefer to use S3 instead of Cloudfront for serving signedUrl, because it is a lot easier.
[Serving files stored in S3 in express/nodejs app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516820/serving-files-stored-in-s3-in-express-nodejs-app)

But some have reproduced what the method getSignedUrl should do for CloudFront.
[Creating signed S3 and Cloudfront URLs via the AWS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521302/creating-signed-s3-and-cloudfront-urls-via-the-aws-sdk)

Thanks to Jason who has even made a package for that. On NPM : https://www.npmjs.org/package/aws-cloudfront-sign

Answer (score 4):

Update: This method is available as of the 2017-03-25 api version of the AWS SDK for Javascript in the AWS.CloudFront.Signer class. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFront/Signer.html