# Is there a way to use http link instead of https in S3 getSignedUrl?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I am currently using **aws-sdk** to download file from S3 using node.js.

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: directory + file,
    Expires: 300
};

var url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
res.redirect(url);
```

And it is giving me a link with https.

```
https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/.......qNBK%2BzP48%3D
```

Is there a way to get link with http instead of https? Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you to use cloudfront for this. take a look here, maybe it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521302/creating-signed-s3-and-cloudfront-urls-via-the-aws-sdk

Comment: Have you tried something like `var s3 = new AWS.S3({sslEnabled: false});` ...?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks Mike, I already used it and solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable SSL download, set `false` in **AWS config**.

```
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: key,
    secretAccessKey: secret,
    sslEnabled: false
});
```

Comment: How to disable in SDK v3?