# Stream Video from secured S3 bucket to videogular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, video, amazon-s3

I have a web application based on AWS. The client is written in JavaScript with Angular 1.5.3

User log in in this app via a Cognito Userpool. That works fine. Some users are able to upload videos and images to a secured S3 bucket. That is also working fine. Now I already implemented the functionality to display images from this secured bucket. Also successful.

Next step is to stream the videos to the browser of logged in users. I want to use e.g. videogular. I have two ideas:

- determine the exact URI of the video and pass it to videogular. This will work for public S3 buckets, but not for secured ones.
- 'somehow' load the video via the AWS JS SDK (which always sets correct auth headers) and stream this to the Html5 website. I have no idea how this could work ...

I think this is a quite regular use case - so maybe someone can help me or point me in the right direction?

I already found this tutorial: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/TutorialStreamingJWPlayer.html
But unfortunately this is of little use, as it describes how to stream from public buckets.

Comment: Did you take a look at this article on how you can serve your private content through CloudFront using signed URLs or signed cookies? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-choosing-signed-urls-cookies.html

Comment: Yes I read the article, but I don't understand how this is possible with the AWS JS SDK. The benefits of the SDK is the setting of credentials and auth headers "under the hood". But when reading this article it looks like I need to take of this myself. I feel quite lost ...

Comment: The SDK also allows you to generate the signed cookies for each logged in user, which allow them to stream any (private) video, or create a signed URL for individual resources / videos. You can find more info on how to create signed cookies/URLs using the SDK here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21536917/3770040

Comment: Your tipps where very helpfull! I managed to achieve what I wanted using signed URLs. If you turn it in an answer I accept it :)

Comment: I'm glad you found my comments useful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-choosing-signed-urls-cookies.html) on how you can serve your private content through CloudFront using signed URLs or signed cookies.

The SDK allows you to generate the signed cookies for each logged in user, which allow them to stream any (private) video, or create a signed URL for individual resources / videos. You can find more info on how to create signed cookies/URLs using the SDK [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21521302/creating-signed-s3-and-cloudfront-urls-via-the-aws-sdk/21536917#21536917).